# Error in reclassifying with ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, raster, reclassify, error-999999

I am trying to reclassify DEM using `arcpy.sa.Reclassify` and it is showing an error.

Following are my commands:

```
dem_re=arcpy.sa.Reclassify("dem_extfish.tif","VALUE",arcpy.sa.RemapRange([[391, 677, 1],[677, 963, 2],[963, 1249, 3],[1249, 1535, 4],[1535, 1821, 5],[1821, 2107, 6],[2107, 2393, 7],[2393, 2679, 8],[2679, 2965, 9],[2965, 3242,10]]))

dem_re.save("reclass_dem_eleband.tif")
```

The above command gives the error:

```
ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
Failed to execute (Reclassify).
```

However, it was reclassified using ArcMap but have been producing the error with ArcPy.

The full error and traceback are as below:

```
ExecuteError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-d371dde30892> in <module>()
----> 1 dem_re=arcpy.sa.Reclassify("dem_extfish.tif","VALUE",arcpy.sa.RemapRange([[391, 677, 1],[677, 963, 2],[963, 1249, 3],[1249, 1535, 4],[1535, 1821, 5],[1821, 2107, 6],[2107, 2393, 7],[2393, 2679, 8],[2679, 2965, 9],[2965, 3242,10]]))

C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\ArcPy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py in Reclassify(in_raster, reclass_field, remap, missing_values)
   5751         reclass_field,
   5752         remap,
-> 5753         missing_values)
   5754 Reclassify.__esri_toolname__ = "Reclassify_sa"
   5755 Reclassify.__esri_toolinfo__ = [

C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\ArcPy\arcpy\sa\Utils.py in swapper(*args, **kwargs)
     51 
     52             try:
---> 53                 result = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     54             finally:
     55                 # Reset the geoprocessor state to the original setting.

C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\ArcPy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py in Wrapper(in_raster, reclass_field, remap, missing_values)
   5745             remap,
   5746             out_raster,
-> 5747             missing_values)
   5748         return _wrapToolRaster(u"Reclassify_sa", unicode(result.getOutput(0)))
   5749     return Wrapper(

C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py in <lambda>(*args)
    508         val = getattr(self._gp, attr)
    509         if callable(val):
--> 510             return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
    511         else:
    512             return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(val)

ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
Failed to execute (Reclassify).
```

Comment: Yes I have set the workspace using `arcpy.env.workspace` but the error is till there

Comment: I have checked minimum and maximum values in arcgis also and its correct.Setting -9999 and 9999 as min and max didnt help. Same error

Answer (score 1):

Cant' be sure of your input or other factors such as your environment extent or cellsize (i can only assume defaults). However the sample code below worked for me using your remap example.  Possibly check your input data and your env settings.

You could also test another tool like Slice() just to verify your input is working.

```
from arcpy.sa import *

# create a sample input with enough values to reclassify based on users remap.
ras1 = CreateRandomRaster("",1, "0 0 1000 1000")
ras2 = ras1 * 1000

remap = RemapRange([[391, 677, 1],
                    [677, 963, 2],
                    [963, 1249, 3],
                    [1249, 1535, 4],
                    [1535, 1821, 5],
                    [1821, 2107, 6],
                    [2107, 2393, 7],
                    [2393, 2679, 8],
                    [2679, 2965, 9],
                    [2965, 3242,10]])


dem_re = Reclassify(ras2,"VALUE",remap)
dem_re.save()
```